# Is there a way to tell Java compiler not to auto box my primitive type

Tags: java

For example, here are two java methods

```
void test(int... values){}
```

And

```
void test(Object... values){}
```

If I make a call with arguments `(1,2,3)`, there will be a compile error.

Also, I just need the facilities of java varargs, and can not declare my methods with argments int[] or Object[].

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, everyone. I know I can explicit cast my arguments to an array but what I want to know is there a way to tell javac not to auto box this invoke statement. Like in C, you can suggest compiler to store a value in a register.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create the array explicitly:

```
foo.test(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

This works precisely as the vararg method would, so the bytecode won't even know the difference, and it'll resolve to the `int...` overload.

The above is essentially equivalent to creating a variable for the `int[]`, and passing that in:

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };
foo.test(ints);
```

There isn't any other way to tell the compiler which overload you want.

Comment: Can not cast to an array neither.

Comment: My code doesn't cast anything, it just explicitly creates the array instead of having the compiler create it for you. The compiled bytecode is _exactly_ the same: "create an array of length 3; store 1 at index 0, 2 at index 1, 3 at index 2." My code just creates the `int[]` directly, rather than having the compiler do it for you as a convenience. There's no other way to get around this issue. Well, you could create an `int[] ints = ...` variable and then pass it in. But one way or another, you're going to have to explicitly create the `int[]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems that there is no way to tell compiler to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly convert and cast to make the actual arguments exactly match one of the formal argument lists, there is no ambiguity:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    test((Object[]) new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 });
  }

  public static void test(int... values) {
    System.out.println("int version called");
  }

  public static void test(Object... values) {
    System.out.println("Object version called");
  }

}
```